# Display incoming call in Android/MainActivity

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am new to Android(3 months old). I want to read an incoming call and display it through MainActivity.
I have extended PhoneStateListener and am able to detect the incoming call/number. Now my question is how do I display this number in the front end. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use broadcast receiver to show incoming or outgoing calls :- 
create a class CallReceiver :-

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }
        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number, intent);
    }
}

public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number, Intent intent) {
    if (lastState == state) {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime, intent);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime, intent);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, number, callStartTime, intent);
            } else if (isIncoming) {
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, number, callStartTime, new Date(), intent);
            } else {
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, number, callStartTime, new Date(), intent);
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
    Intent intent1 = new Intent("CallApp");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
}

protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "calling from " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "calling to " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "calling from " + number + " ended ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "calling to " + number + " ended ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "missed call from " + number + " sim ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

or register your app in manifest :-

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcaestReceiver.CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```